# Razor: Cannot render Html.Label helper in a @Section (outputting source only)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, rendering, asp.net-mvc-migration

I was unable to figure out how to use @class inside Html.LabelFor, so I updated an extension helper for Html.Label with code found on SO.

My LabelExtension.cs file has the following class:

```
 public static class LabelExtensions
    {
        public static string Label(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                string labelFor,
                                string value,
                                object htmlAttributes)
        {
            TagBuilder labelBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelFor))
            {
                labelBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", labelFor);
            }
            labelBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
            labelBuilder.SetInnerText(value);
            return labelBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        } 
    }
```

I originally used the following in a MVC2 .aspx page thusly (which I am converting to .cshtml):

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %> <%= Html.Label("txt_name_udq", "Your First Name (required):",
                new {
                @class
                = "mylabelstyle" } )%>
                <br />
                <%= Html.TextBox("txt_name_udq", null, new {
                @class
                = "myinputstyle" } )%>
                <br />
                <%= Html.Label("txt_email_udq", "Your E-Mail Address (required):", new {
                @class
                = "mylabelstyle" } )%>
                <br />
                <%= Html.TextBox("txt_email_udq", null, new {
                @class
                = "myinputstyle" })%>
                <br />
                <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

This rendered very well in MVC2 (I left out usings and such for brevity) .  However, today while converting to .cshtml (using a _layout.cshtml) I found that the Html.Label is not rendering and instead outputting source.  Here is the code:

```
@section QuoteForm
{
    <div class="entryfull">
        <div class="entryfull_box">
            <div class="entryfull_text">
                <h2>
                    Quote Request
                </h2>
                <ul class="ul-check">
                    <li>Free</li>
                    <li>Confidential</li>
                    <li>Anonymous</li>
                    <li>No Obligation</li>
                </ul>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.Label("txt_name_udq", "Your First Name (required):", new { @class = "mylabelstyle" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBox("txt_name_udq", null, new { @class = "myinputstyle" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.Label("txt_email_udq", "Your E-Mail Address (required):", new { @class = "mylabelstyle" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBox("txt_email_udq", null, new { @class = "myinputstyle" })
                    <br />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The above is just something simple, not final product.  I am just trying to get it to render first.  Note: 1) I tried various iterations of Html.BeginForm; and 2) I even enclosed it in .  Still, its not "working".

Here is what you see on the browser for the label (source outputted in browswer), right above the textbox (which renders):

```
<label class="mylabelstyle" for="txt_name_udq">Your First Name (required):</label>;
```

And if you "View Source", here is what you see:

```
&lt;label class=&quot;mylabelstyle&quot; for=&quot;txt_name_udq&quot;&gt;Your First Name (required):&lt;/label&gt;;
```

Is this something to do with @section? Or is it that I am trying to use an extension from MVC2?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/advice.

**EDIT**: This is the code I reference in the comment that worked in my situation.  Thanks for the help.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string labelFor, string value,
                                      object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("for", labelFor.Replace(".", tagBuilder.IdAttributeDotReplacement), true);
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(value);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your helper is returning a string and that is encoded by default. Your helper should return MvcHtmlString and change the return statement to

```
 return new MvcHtmlString(labelBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. My labels are now rendering as intended with the CSS class. See my above edit for the code that worked in my particular situation.

Comment: The way my code was written in the .cs file it said that MvcHtmlString does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments